# How to import a csv file to firebase firestore and making it's ID field as id of documents?

Tags: firebase, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a CSV file with 50 entries. I want to import all of that to the Firebase Firestore database. Is there a convenient way to accomplish this task? I am new to all of this, pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a magic button that can help you import a CSV file directly to Firestore, please note that there isn't one. You have to write code for that. So read the content of the file and right after that [add that data to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Comment: Hey Harsh. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: thanks for your help , I read the docs and uploaded my data on Firebase in the required format

Answer (score 0):

Firefoo is good in directly importing CSV file and customizing data.

https://www.firefoo.app/